# hiding output while still capturing it subprocess

Tags: python, grep, subprocess

```
grep = subprocess.run(#command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
result = grep.stdout
text = result.decode('utf-8')
```

When I run this script, I usually get no console output, but sometimes I get this:

"100%|████████████████████████████████████| 112/112 [00:17<00:00,  6.54it/s]"

or this:

"Error (GDocs): request gives 500"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My unwanted console outputs were from stderr. When I set stderr equal to stdout, both were stopped from giving an output to console.

```
grep = subprocess.run(#command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=stdout, shell=True)
result = grep.stdout
text = result.decode('utf-8')
```